# Can I get the index of a repeated character in a series in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to index a letter from a string in dataframe and place it in a new column.

```
d = {'col1': ['SYDYGENESD',
              'SSYDYGENE'], 
     'col2': ['A', 'B']}

d = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This is what I tried to do but it is only returning the lowest (first) `'Y'` not the others.

```
d['new_col'] = d['col1'].str.index('Y')
```

I also tried:

```
d['new_col'] = d['col1'].str.rindex('Y')
```

but it only returns the highest index. Can I do something like this code in pandas? So, it returns a list of all the index of `'Y'` in `col1`

Also, I tried

```
def ind(my_list, desired_element):
    return [index for index, element in enumerate(my_list) if element == desired_element]

d['new_col'] = d.apply(lambda x: ind(d['col1'],'Y'), axis=1)
```

The desired dataframe is:

```
target = {'col1': ['SYDYGENESD', 'SSYDYGENE'],
          'col2': ['A','B'],
          'col3':[[1, 3],[2, 4]]}
target = pd.DataFrame(data=target)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close, I think the only thing going wrong is your `apply` syntax:

You can define a function that detects the indices of `"Y"` in a string and then apply it to `col1`:

```
def duplicates(lst, item):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == item]


d['col3'] = d['col1'].apply(lambda x: duplicates(x, "Y"))

#          col1 col2    col3
# 0  SYDYGENESD    A  [1, 3]
# 1   SSYDYGENE    B  [2, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well :) As you said, it was a mistake in my `apply` syntax. Thank you again

Comment: You can also use `return np.where(np.array(list(lst))==item)[0]`, although list comprehension is properly faster.